# Array, prevent user to write same value

Tags: c#, arrays, list, duplicates

I'm using an Array to save my numbers, however i don't want userInput to be equal to a same value in the array.  int[] userNum = new int[100];
if userInput is 1, and 1 has already been stored in the array, i want the code to tell the user
"wrong input"  I tried with userNum[i] != userNum[i], Did not work.
I'm not working with lists at this moment, but i'm planning on going there very soon. right now i'm trying to understand array's better, and how to work with them. I'm glad with all help i can get with this.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < userNum.Length; i++)
            { 
            try
            {
                array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Number {0}", (i + 1));
            }
            catch (SystemException)
            {
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input try again");

                continue;
            }
            if (userNum[i] < min || userNum[i] >
                max || userNum[i] != userNum[i])  // this does not work
            {
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, try again");
                continue;
            }
            }
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through each stored element, and check if the new element matches with them. If it does, that means, it has already been stored, and therefore, the number is invalid. Else, you store it.

```
if (userNum[i] < min || userNum[i] > max) {
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, try again");
                continue;
}
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    if(userNum[i] == userNum[j]) {
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, try again");
                break;
    //TODO something to "continue;" if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Zenkii1337 Thank you for taking your time! 
I never thought about this approach, for some reason, i thought my code looped and checked the value that was stored.  I appriciate your help. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a list that has a "Contains" method to see if already in a list or not.

```
public void EnterNumbers()
{
    var myInts = new List<int>();
    int tryConvert;
    while( myInts.Count < 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number not already in list: ");
        var userEntry = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(userEntry, out tryConvert))
        {
            // if WAS able to convert to a number, now check if in the list
            if (myInts.Contains(tryConvert))
                Console.WriteLine("Number already in list");
            else
                myInts.Add(tryConvert);
        }
        else
        {
            // allow user to enter a "Q" to quit vs adding all 100 entries
            if (userEntry == "Q")
                break;

            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks DRapp, thank you for taking your time.  I've seen a similar approach to "fixing the issue" as you stated, i find this very good, however i'm still not really sure if Arrays are better or lists. 
I know that they are similare, however i'm going to dive a bit futher in and try to understand them better. 
thanks again.

Comment: @UndeadSpace, List are good as you can still cycle through them with index position [0], [1], etc... and loop based on myInts.Count vs a fixed known number.  Also can be used for binding, such as to data grids and such and you can have lists of other things as well (records from a database query).  But find what works for you.

Comment: I'm still a beginner in coding, and not yet informed how to utilize code at its best. I hope i'll be able to help others like you in the future. 
Thanks again.  
Will look into data grids and how to use lists in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your array `userNum` contains new input with `Contains` method:

```
if (userNum.Contains(array[i]))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Invalid input, {array[i]} already present.");
}
```

I'd also suggest to use slightly simpler approach and different data structure (`HashSet`) to achieve the same result but with less code. Another minor suggestion - let the user know what why is their input number invalid. For example:

```
        public void ReadValues()
        {
            var min = -100;
            var max = 100;
            var successfulInputCount = 0;
            var userNum = new HashSet<int>();
            while (successfulInputCount < 100)
            {
                try
                {
                    var input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (input < min || input > max)
                        Console.WriteLine($"Invalid input, number must be between {min} and {max}.");

                    var added = userNum.Add(input);
                    if (added)
                        successfulInputCount++;
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine($"Invalid input, {input} already present.");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Invalid input, try again. Error message: {e.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Tomaz for taking your time!
I've been experimenting with HashSet, however i don't feel confident yet to use it.  
From my understanding, Lists are better for bigger projekts? i'm trying to use lists more, but working frequently with arrays. 
I see that you are using Var pretty often, is there a reason why you're not hardcoding datatype? such as int, double.

Comment: Cheers mate, you're welcome. 

Regarding HashSet vs Array: it's not very important for smaller projects (or array size) but it's good to know the difference to be able to use the right data structure when it does make a difference. Besides the speed of `Contains` method, which requires O(1) for a HashSet, but O(N) for an array, it also guards against duplicates - if you use HashSet, there's no way you can have a bug in your code that inserts a duplicate into it, while you need to make sure it doesn't if you use an array.

Comment: As for `var`, it's just a nice and modern feature of newer C# versions (quite old already). You don't have to repeat variable's type - for example, if you define an array or hashset of integers, why repeat type in front of variable declaration. You just type `var`and your compiler (and IDE in most cases) figures the correct type. Also, if you need to change your variable, let's say you need to have an array of doubles, you change it in one place only, it's just less fuss. There are lots of other benefits (and very few, if any, cons) you can check on other pages.

Comment: Thanks again Tomaz for clearfying, i'll sit down and read more on HashSet, it feels as it's a bit superior in future work(as i will be working on bigger projects). 
 I'll also start using var more often, as i've run into the exakt problem as you stated with needing to change datatype. 
thanks again!
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want better performance you should hashset instead.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1#examples

It has time complexity 1 for Contains method.
Also method **Add** si very helpful
returns true if the element is added to the HashSet object; false if the element is already present.

If you need to turn the hashset into array for some reason at the and of the input you can easily do with

using System.Linq;

```
var mySet = new HashSet<int>();
// load input data
var myArray = mySet.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've been sitting on youtube and other platforms to learn more about HashSet, From what i can understand it's a lot faster, and easier to shape and bend code later on. I will be diving deeper on HashSet. 
I appriciate your help! oh and awesome transition from HashSet to array. i'll definitely use it. 

Best regards